# I copied database to external storage. but it haven't source tables

Tags: android, sqlite, file, copy

I copied a database from the internal storage to external, but it seems that something was wrong. Because there is no table in it.
I feel just an empty file is created.
Meanwhile, I used ActiveAndroid to create the source database file and use Filechanel to copy file

```
public class DbExportImport {

/** Directory that files are to be read from and written to **/
protected static final File DATABASE_DIRECTORY =
        new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"mydirectory");

public static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "example.com.testp";

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database1.db";

/** Contains: /data/data/com.example.app/databases/example.db **/
private static final File DATA_DIRECTORY_DATABASE =
        new File(Environment.getDataDirectory() +
                "/data/" + PACKAGE_NAME +
                "/databases/" + DATABASE_NAME );

public static  boolean exportDb(){

  // if external torage is present
  if( ! SdIsPresent() ) return false;

    File dbFile = DATA_DIRECTORY_DATABASE;

    String filename = "backupdb.db";

    File exportDir = DATABASE_DIRECTORY;

    File file = new File(exportDir, filename);

    if (!exportDir.exists()) {
        exportDir.mkdirs();
    }

    try {
        file.createNewFile();
        copyFile(dbFile, file);
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}


private static void copyFile(File src, File dst) throws IOException {

    FileChannel inChannel = new FileInputStream(src).getChannel();

    FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream(dst).getChannel();

    try {
                  inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
    } finally {
        if (inChannel != null)
            inChannel.close();
        if (outChannel != null)
            outChannel.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that it has no tables? None of the above code tries to look at the database as an sqlite database it just treats it as an ordinary file.

Comment: hello. i see in copied database with sqlite3 command line program.but there is no table in it .

Comment: You have likely opened the database with an sqlite command/method when it didn't exist and thus the database has been created with no tables. e.g. `SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("mydb",MODE_PRIVATE,null);` will do just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the same thing on all devices (i use LG SmartPhone to test)
The problem was the extension of the file(.db). We should not write it to access database in private storage /data/data ...
I used context.getDatabasePath() to get database path in a safe way.
in exportDb function i use `copyFile(context.getDatabasePath("database1"),file)` instead of `copyFile(dbFile, file);`
or you can change `public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database1.db";`to `public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database1";`
But the first approach seems to be safer